# generate random numbers that are different from each other Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My table generates 7 random boxes in blue, and 5 other random boxes in yellow, but my problem is that sometimes a boxd "Id" can have 2 or 3 times the same random value, and we see only 5 blue boxes, not 7 as expected. How can I fix it? If the boxe is blue, it can not be a second time, if it is blue, it can not be yellow, etc.

```
function bluecolor() {
  $(".boutton2").click(function() {
      for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28) + 1;

        $("#" + rn).addClass("blue");
      }
      for (a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        var randome = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28) + 1;
        $("#" + randome).addClass("yellow");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It would probably also help people to read your prior questions as this is a varient of an answer to one of those.

Comment: Yes but the prior question was well answered

Answer (score 2):

I see in your code that seems you have 29 boxes, not 12, numbered from 1 to 29. I understant that you want 7 of them in blue and 5 in yellow. Right?

You could make an array with the 28 ids (numbers 1 to 29), them "shuffle" it, and asign class blue to the first 7, yellow to the next 5... (and remove the classes for the others if needed).

(take a look to [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array))

Comment: Yes this is what I need, ok I watch it

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `$("#" + randome).length > 0` to verify if the id is already added or  `$(".myClass").length > 0` if you want use a class for this.

You can also use a array and verify the numbers and just pick different numbers.

```js
var numbers = [];

while(numbers.length < 5){
   var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 28) + 1;
   if(numbers.indexOf(number) == -1){
      numbers.push(number);
   }
}
console.log(numbers);
```

You can make a function and use multiple times:

```js
function getRandomNotEqualNumbers(quantity, max, min){
  var numbers = [];

  while(numbers.length < quantity){
     var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    if(numbers.indexOf(number) == -1){
       numbers.push(number);
    }
  }
  return numbers;
}

var blues = getRandomNotEqualNumbers(7, 28, 1);
var yellows = getRandomNotEqualNumbers(5, 28, 1);

console.log(blues);
console.log(yellows);

//if you want unique between colors
var myNumbers = getRandomNotEqualNumbers(12, 28, 1);
blues = [];
yellows = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myNumbers.length; i++){
  if(i < 7)
    blues[i] = myNumbers[i];
  else
    yellows[i-7] = myNumbers[i];
}

console.log(blues);
console.log(yellows);
```

Comment: It works for only one color, how can I make it for 2 colors ?.. Blue and Yellow

Comment: run this twice? i will create a function to make more clear

Comment: No I mean, I have 7 blue and 5 yellow that's ok, but some times I have 5 blue and 5 yellow, should I create a big "while" chich containes the two colors ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeating numbers make an arraylist with every number you generate.